# How to redirect and send variables of the current logged in correctly?

Tags: javascript, velo

Hello how are you ? I'm new to javascript and I need help with a question. I'm trying to send data of the current logged in member and redirect a different domain via a button on the website creation [www.wix.com](http://www.wix.com). The data are status, full name, email and id. The language used is javascript.
I would like to know what I do to be able to send this data together in the url and what I'm doing wrong in the code.

```
import { currentMember } from 'wix-members';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

export function button2_click(event) {
  wixLocation.to("www.page.com" + currentMember.getMember().then((member) => {
      const id = member._id;
      const status = member.status
      const fullName = `${member.contactDetails.firstName} ${member.contactDetails.lastName}`;
      return member;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: [getMember](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-members-backend/currentmember/getmember) returns a promise, not member details.  You will have to await the result.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: "www.page.com" is a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research on the Wix Velo forum, I discovered the `members-wix` API, at the moment it is having problems, which results in looking for functions in the users-wix API, but it is deprecated, which hides functions on the site the fleece making access to information difficult. However, after copying a migration function from `users-wix` to `members-wix`, along with `members-wix` authentication, it worked perfectly, I also want to thank Mosh Feu for help https://stackoverflow.com /users/863110/mosh-feu, which helped me understand and improve this code.

```
import { currentMember } from 'wix-members';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import { authentication } from 'wix-members';
// NOTE: This example uses the new wix-members.currentMember.getMember()
// function, which replaces wix-users.currentUser.
// See the function description for more information, and
// line 36 for the deprecated example.

// ...

currentMember.getMember('FULL')
    .then((member) => {
        // Replaces currentUser.id
        const id = member._id;

        // Replaces currentUser.loggedIn
        const loggedIn = member ? true : false;

        // Replaces currentUser.getEmail()
        const loginEmail = member.loginEmail;
        const contactEmails = member.contactDetails.emails;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

currentMember.getRoles()
    .then((roles) => {
        // Replaces currentUser.role and currentUser.getRoles()
        return roles;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

// NOTE: This example uses the deprecated
// wix-users.currentUser object.

import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

// ...

let user = wixUsers.currentUser;

let userId = user.id; // "r5cme-6fem-485j-djre-4844c49"
let isLoggedIn = user.loggedIn; // true

user.getEmail()
    .then((email) => {
        let userEmail = email; // "user@something.com"
    });

user.getRoles()
    .then((roles) => {
        let firstRole = roles[0];
        let roleName = firstRole.name; // "Role Name"
        let roleDescription = firstRole.description; // "Role Description"
    });

user.getPricingPlans()
    .then((pricingPlans) => {
        let firstPlan = pricingPlans[0];
        let planName = firstPlan.name; // "Gold"
        let startDate = firstPlan.startDate; // Wed Aug 29 2018 09:39:41 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
        let expirationDate = firstPlan.expiryDate; // Thu Nov 29 2018 08:39:41 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
    });
export async function button2_click(event) {
    authentication.onLogin(async(member) => {
        const loggedInMember = await member.getMember();
        const memberId = loggedInMember._id;
        console.log(`Member ${memberId} logged in:`, loggedInMember);
    });

    const member = await currentMember.getMember();
    const id = member._id;
    const status = member.status;
    const email = member.loginEmail
    const fullName = `${member.contactDetails.firstName} ${member.contactDetails.lastName}`;
    const userDetails = JSON.stringify({ id, status, fullName ,email });

    wixLocation.to(`https://www.url.com/?user=${encodeURIComponent(userDetails)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As James mentioned, `getMember` return Promise so you should wait (`await`) or the Promise to fulfilled with the data before you can use it.
2. You are trying to concat an object (the user details) with string (the url). It's not possible in Javascript. You can "convert" the object to string using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).
3. Even if the object is string, the URL you are trying to redirect to is not valid e.g. `www.page.com{id:1111,status:'active'}`. The valid way to pass data via the url is by query params e.g.`www.page.com?userDetails={id:1111,status:'active'}`.
   Just to be on the safe side, encode the stringified object with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
export async function button2_click(event) {
  const member = await currentMember.getMember();
  const id = member._id;
  const status = member.status
  const fullName = `${member.contactDetails.firstName} ${member.contactDetails.lastName}`;
  const userDetails = JSON.stringify({id, status, fullName});
  
  wixLocation.to(`www.page.com?user=${encodeURIComponent(userDetails)}`);
}
```

(You can use the "`then` approach" you are using now but it's a good opportunity to use more modern API such as async/await)

Comment: Thank you for helping. "www.page.com" is a example.  Now I can see other errors in velo: Error: Ambassador client request failed:
HTTP STATUS: -1
RESPONSE: "Failed to fetch"
See the httpStatus and response fields for more information. But i don´t create nothing to receive in the other url. Do I have to create first to it works ?

Comment: Of course it's an example. What is the right url? Is it your sote or an external link? If it's an external link, I believe you should include the URL scheme (http or https)

Comment: It´s a external server with web app in google cloud , i can´t say the right link because is not mine and  there´s not "www" . I´ve tried with http and https, but it´s not working too.

Comment: The other error apeers in Developement tools : is has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Error: Ambassador client request failed:
HTTP STATUS: -1
RESPONSE: "Failed to fetch"
See the httpStatus and response fields for more information.
    at new t (wixcode-users.js:3288:1)
    at t.handleFetchErrors (wixcode-users.js:3344:1)
    at handleErrors (wixcode-users.js:3326:1)
e.<computed> @ console.js:35

Comment: Mosh, I discovered wix-members API has problems nowadays. So, i figured out how to fix the problem . I will post another answer with part of your code and mine.